# How can I expect two parameters of a function to be of the same value of a specific Union type

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics, type-annotation

I am trying to create a function that takes two parameters, first is a union type, second is type that depends on the type of the first parameter.

For example:

```ts
type Fruit = "Orange" | "Apple" | "Banana";

function doubleFruit<T extends Fruit, K extends T>(fruit1: T, fruit2: K) {
   // When execution reaches here
   // both fruit1 and fruit2 need to be the same fruit
}
```

---

Now, These statements work as expected

```ts
 
 // Gives error since Orange is not same as Apple neither banana
 doubleFruit("Orange", "Apple"); 
 doubleFruit("Orange", "Banana");

 // Runs peacefully, since both are same fruit
 doubleFruit("Apple", "Apple");
```

---

But when the first parameter is dynamic, something strange happens

```ts
function run(x: "Orange" | "Apple") {

 // Should not work, since x could be anything
 doubleFruit(x, "Orange");
}
```

I assume that since `x` could be either `Orange` or `Apple`, the second parameter being `Orange` does not follow the criteria of both parameters being same.

Edit:
Here's what I want to achieve

```ts
type Fruit = "Orange" | "Apple" | "Banana";


function doubleFruit<T extends Fruit, K extends T>(fruit1: T, fruit2: K) {
  // When execution reaches here
  // both fruit1 and fruit2 need to be the same fruit
}

function run(x: "Orange" | "Apple") {
  // I need this to work: 
  //   Whatever be the value of x, the other parameter would be equivalent,
  //   hence should be allowed
  doubleFruit(x, x); 

  // But not these: 
  //   since x could be anything, specifically sending one of 
  //   values shouldn't work
  doubleFruit(x, "Orange")
  doubleFruit(x, "Apple")
  
}
```

I need a way to satisfy the above behaviour.

Comment: It kinda works like quantum physics. When the value of `fruit1` is not certain, its type is `"Orange" | "Apple"`, so `fruit2` can be either one of them (so `"Orange"` satisfies the condition). However when `fruit1` is a fixed value `"Orange"`, its type is collapsed into the type `"Orange"`, so `fruit2` can only be its subset which is also `"Orange"`.

Comment: What, specifically, is the question here?  Is it "why is this happening" or "how can I make a function that behaves as desired"?  If it's the former, I could explain how generics and unions work together.  If it's the latter, then I'd make `doubleFruit` non-generic like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wjXalm) shows.  Let me know how to proceed here (please ping @jcalz if you reply so that I'm notified.)

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz, Actually, I wanted to ask both of them, like "Why is this happening", since I expected it to give me an error, I understand that x can be both hence the second parameter is allowed but I expected both of them to be same, because the type of both values is same. Second, I also need to find a way to solve my issue, The above given is just an example, I want the second parameter to somehow depend upon the real-time type of the first parameter. The solution you provided does solve the issue but then there is another issue, you may see it [here](https://tsplay.dev/weBadN)

Comment: There’s supposed to be just one question per post. Could you pick one primary question? And if the answer doesn’t suffice then you could make another post for the other question?

Comment: Okay, I need to find the answer to the second question, how can I make it work? you may see the code [here](https://tsplay.dev/WG4B0w)

Comment: (If you don't write @jcalz when you reply, then I'm not notified.)  Please [edit] the question to make it clear what the question is and what your use cases are (if the link you provided above is another important use case, then it should be in the question itself).

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, I have added my use case in the question, (and sorry for the delay), please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Please try if that is working for your case:

```
type Fruit = "Orange" | "Apple" | "Banana";

function doubleFruit<T extends Fruit, K>(fruit1: T, fruit2: K & T) {
   // When execution reaches here
   // both fruit1 and fruit2 need to be the same fruit
}

doubleFruit("Orange", "Apple"); 
doubleFruit("Orange", "Banana");

doubleFruit("Apple", "Apple");

const x: "Orange" | "Apple" = "Apple";

doubleFruit(x, "Orange");
```

Comment: Thanks, @dbonev, This works as expected but I believe here TypeScript somehow managed to remember the value of x, so it knows that "Orange won't " satisfy the condition, but if the value of x was Orange it won't be throwing any error. though it's a good feature to have that TypeScript keeps the information of the context, but I expect it to throw an error in scenarios where the context doesn't provide enough information, like in the function `run` in the question.